# How to use regex in reverse while statement

Tags: perl, while-loop, reverse

```
open IN, "in.txt";
open OUT, ">out.txt";

print OUT unless m[^foo] while <IN>;
```

Why doesn't the above code compile?

Comment: Just some terminology that might help you in future searches: what you're calling a reverse while statement is a statement modifier.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the notation that allows you to write `if`/`unless`/`while` as a suffix to a line of code can only be used once in that line. So you have to replace the last line in you code with:

```
while (<IN>) {
    print OUT unless m[^foo];
}
```

An alternative for this case it to use an `or`:

```
m[^foo] or print OUT while <IN>;
```

Comment: Can brackets be used to allow more than one reverse statement in the one line?

Comment: @CJ7 No, unfortunately there is not way to do it with braces or brackets other that the first snippet I gave above.